# WPF DataGrid Hide selected row?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, visibility

Is there a way to "hide" the SelectedItem of the DataGrid ?

```
dataGrid.SelectedItem.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
```

Comment: The actual row of data or the highlighting/border on the default template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the Visibility of "SelectedItem", as you have, would not change the grid - it would be changing the "SelectedItem" property value of the bound object for that SelectedItem, which is not going to affect the grid at all.

In order to change the grid row's visibility, you'll need to change it directly.  You can retemplate the DataGrid to change how the selected row is displayed.

For details, see [DataGrid Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff506248.aspx).